# How should we approach sufism answers?

Tags: discussion

Some people could approach questions in a sufism point of view, for example, consider the question "Why do Muslims pray 5 times a day?", some might answer as "Because it is a must, see this source ...", however, someone with sufism background may answer it like "5 times pray a day symbolizes the journey of human. Salat Al-Sabah makes a person remember creation, and also being revived in afterlife ..." (that is may or may not be true, I am just trying to give example), or someone else may answer it with "Praying 5 times a day make you remember Allah (c.c) all day long, and will strengten your belief."

Should we allow answer sufism or islamic thought questions, or should answer cite sources and be exact?

Answer (score 7):

The key is to treat each answer as information, not necessarily the ultimate truth. So if someone comes and says "Sufis view prayer as such and such" then that should be fine. They can even cite references for this as the work of some classical scholar, and that's fine as well.

Answer (score 6):

I think is this site we should aim to be as broad as possible, despite our own personal beliefs. If you are aware that a certain question has varying answers within different sects or schools of thought, then I think the academically honest thing to do is to cite all of them, even if you (personally) disagree with most of them. Let the reader himself decide which viewpoint is the correct one.